# What is the perfect strategy to lock tables in MySql?

Tags: mysql, locking

I have wrote this procedure which creates new A/c voucher. It runs on MySql 5.0. Now, it's time to implement this in our production. But I am not sure that it meets the requirement. Is this Lock Strategy perfect ? Please help.

It calls this way :

```
CALL SpAcVoucherCreate(1,'2022/03/31','2831',5000,'A001');
```

My procedure is as follows :

```
USE `FinanceDB`;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `SpAcVoucherCreate`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SpAcVoucherCreate`(
    V_VOCHNO    INT,
    V_VOCHDT    CHAR(10),
    V_ACCODE    CHAR(4),
    V_AMOUNT    DECIMAL(12,2),
    V_USER_ID   CHAR(5)
    )
BEGIN

DECLARE V_ERR_OCCURED   BOOLEAN;

SET V_ERR_OCCURED=FALSE;

BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
SET V_ERR_OCCURED=TRUE;

SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
START TRANSACTION;

LOCK TABLES `ACTRANS` WRITE;

INSERT INTO ACTRANS
        (VOCHNO,VOCHDT,ACCODE,AMOUNT,USER_ID)
        VALUES
        (V_VOCHNO,V_VOCHDT,V_ACCODE,V_AMOUNT,V_USER_ID);

IF V_ERR_OCCURED=TRUE THEN
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
    COMMIT;
END IF;

UNLOCK TABLES;

SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;

END;

    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: mysql 5.0 has not been supported for many many years.  do not use it.

Answer (score 2):

I find the procedure to be doing several things that are unnecessary.

- SERIALIZABLE acts the same as REPEATABLE READ for what you're doing. The only effect of SERIALIZABLE in MySQL is that it makes non-locking SELECT statements into locking SELECT statements as if you had used SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE. Since you only do an INSERT, this difference has no effect.
- There's no need to disable autocommit and then do a transaction start and commit/rollback for a single statement. If you had left autocommit enabled, then a successful INSERT would commit, and an unsuccessful INSERT would not commit. It would have the same result as your code.
- There would be no need for an SQLEXCEPTION handler to rollback the transaction, because you have only a single statement in the transaction. It either succeeds or it does not succeed.
- Regardless of any of the above, you have shown no reason to use LOCK TABLES. It will only block INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE unnecessarily, if multiple clients try to add rows concurrently. If there is a special reason you need to do this, you have not described it.
- Your procedure body has an unnecessary BEGIN/END block. It doesn't do anything. Also I believe that DECLARE is only allowed following the first BEGIN, not within other blocks in the body.
- There is probably no reason to use a stored procedure at all, since it only accomplishes a single INSERT operation. Why not just do the INSERT directly in the client? I suppose if you want to restrict the privilege to do inserts to the procedure, if the user doesn't have that privilege, that would be a reason.

I also agree with the comment above that you are using a version of MySQL that is suspiciously out of date. MySQL 5.0 passed its end of life date in 2012, according to https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql. You are missing many bug fixes, security patches, and of course modern features.

---

Update:

The comment from SolarFlare is correct, one is not allowed to use `LOCK` or `UNLOCK` statements in stored procedures in MySQL:

```
mysql> create procedure p()
    -> begin
    -> lock tables mytable write;
    -> insert into mytable () values ();
    -> unlock tables;
    -> end//
ERROR 1314 (0A000): LOCK is not allowed in stored procedures
```

Comment: First of all, I am forced to use MySql 5.0 because we are using legacy program which uses Strauts 1.1 FW. Now I am assigned to upgrade it to Spring Boot. But DB will be the same.
In this procedure, I use near about 5 tables to be inserted/updated. But here, I showed only one table insertion.
I am calling this Stored Procedure through a Spring Boot Repository using SimpleJdbcCall with MapSqlParameterSource. That's why I can't directly the Sql commands. It will break the 'Loose Coupling' technique.
I will go through your advise in detail and I will let you know about this.
Thanks to you.

Comment: Apart from having no reason to use "lock tables" in the stored procedure, it's also not possible to use "lock tables" in a stored procedure.

Comment: Using `MapSqlParameterSource` does not mean you have to use stored procedures. Here's an example tutorial showing use of Spring Boot and `MapSqlParameterSource` with a plain INSERT statement: https://roytuts.com/spring-namedparameterjdbctemplate-and-mapsqlparametersource-example/